# Xcode continuous integration -- build any/all branches

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode5, osx-server

Currently, when creating a bot, you must specify a specific branch to build.  Is there any way to create a bot that builds all branches, or branch names matching a pattern?

Note: this is a [cross-post from the Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/908310#908310).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You have to configure multiple bots, each with a different branch. See WWDC 2013 session 412 Best Practices (slide 137) which says to create a new bot per branch.